# Making a vector bundle ample by twisting with ample line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, line-bundles, ample-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective algebraic variety over some field (I am happy to add some more assumptions if necessary). A vector bundle $E$ is *ample* if the relative twisting sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}(E)}(1)$ is an ample line bundle on the projective bundle $\mathbf{P}(E)$ of hyperplanes in $E$. Now let $E$ be an arbitrary vector bundle and let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. Will $E \otimes L^{\otimes n}$ be an ample vector bundle for $n \gg 0$? Of course it would suffice if the pullback of $L$ to $\mathbf{P}(E)$ was still ample. But in general pullbacks of ample line bundles won't remain ample.

Comment: There is a classical result of Hartshorne (PMIHES, 1966), saying that $E$ is ample iff $O_{P(E^∗)}(1)$ is ample on $P(E^∗)$. By Hartshorne Ex.II.7.10 it follows $P(E^*) \cong P((E\otimes L)^*)$ for any line bundle $L$.

Comment: The exercise in Hartshorne holds for any $X$ that is regular and Noetherian. I have not done the exercise myself - I would advice you to do it.

Comment: @hm2020 Yes, more precisely, under the identification $\mathbf{P}(E \otimes L^{\otimes n}) = \mathbf{P}(E)$, the line bundle $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{P}(E \otimes L^{\otimes n})}(1)$ corresponds to $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{P}(E)}(1) \otimes \pi^*(L)^{\otimes n}$. Therefore, it would be enough to know that $\pi^*(L)$ be ample, as I remarked in my question.

Comment: First prove that $E\otimes L^{\otimes n}$ is a quotient of the trivial bundle for $n>>0$. You have now reduced the result to proving that $p_1^{*}\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes p_2^{*} L^{\otimes m}$ is very-ample on $\mathbb{P}^N\times X$ for $m$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @user279422 - whenever you use a result from and exercise in a book (like Hartshorne) you should of course do the exercise yourself before using it in you research.

Comment: @Kapil Thank you! The fact that by twisting I can make $E$ globally generated is for example contained in Theorem 6.1.10 in Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry II*. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $L$ is ample, $E\otimes L^n$ is generated by global sections for $n\gg 0$, i.e., there is a surjective morphism $\mathscr O_X^{\oplus r} \to E\otimes L^n$, which implies that there is a surjective morphism $L^{\oplus r} \to E\otimes L^{n+1}$. As $L$ is ample, so is $L^{\oplus r}$ and then so is its quotient $E\otimes L^{n+1}$.